# How to detect the colors of detected shapes OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, colors, object-detection, color-detection

I wrote the code bellow to detect 3D shapes in an image and it works correctly.

Now I need to detect the colors inside the shapes and calculate them.

Could anyone point me where should I start with color detection?

**Code for shape detection below, maybe it will be of use:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.imshow('Original Image',rawImage) 
cv2.waitKey(0)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(rawImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('HSV Image',hsv)
cv2.waitKey(0)

hue ,saturation ,value = cv2.split(hsv)
cv2.imshow('Saturation Image',saturation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

retval, thresholded = cv2.threshold(saturation, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('Thresholded Image',thresholded)
cv2.waitKey(0)

medianFiltered = cv2.medianBlur(thresholded,5)
cv2.imshow('Median Filtered Image',medianFiltered)
cv2.waitKey(0) 

cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(medianFiltered, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in cnts:
# compute the center of the contour
M = cv2.moments(c)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])


first = cv2.drawContours(rawImage, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
second =cv2.circle(rawImage, (cX, cY),1 , (255, 255, 255), -1)


cv2.imshow('Objects Detected',rawImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Centers of shapes founded as we can see, when we do print(second) we get a output of all pixels But I need output just from the pixel inside contour,with this method is that imposible to get values from pixel inside in contour?]

Comment: What do you mean by `calculate them`? Represent them as `RGB` values, as HTML hex-codes?

Comment: I think you mean calculating the dominant color. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43111221/10699171) shows an implementation.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I mean,for example; If in the input image there are totally 5 cubes with three different colors I need output like 2 cubes are red,2 cubes yellow and 1 red.

Comment: @J.D. I mean calculating the colors which are inside in the shapes.For example if we have an image with 6 circles composed of tree colors(blue,white,yellow),I need to recognize the colors and get output like 2 circles are blue,2 white and 2 yellow.

Comment: I can't help feeling it would help if we could see your image...

Comment: just check pixel value for example in the middle of your shape. It is safe to assume that a pixel in the middle represents your shape color.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I uploaded the image also.Can you see now?

Comment: Yes. For each contour, find the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` coordinates and average those to find the centre of the shape. Use Numpy slicing to take a, say, 5x5 pixel square centred on that point. Now take the mean of the red, green and blue channels in that square as the ball's colour.

Comment: You state in a comment above that the output you want is '2 circles are blue, 2 are yellow'. First use the center of shape method to get the colors. Next you have to associate the colors with words / categories. This is easiest if to convert the found colors to HSV colorspace [(How to)](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#how-to-find-hsv-values-to-track). You can then associate a range of hue with a word / category. For example Hue 50-70 is green  [(graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSKh8.png).

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for advice.I get the center of shapes with the code bellow :  `M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])`... Then we drowe the contours, and  circles in the center of shapes -  `first = cv2.drawContours(rawImage, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    second =cv2.circle(rawImage, (cX, cY),1 , (255, 255, 255), -1)` ..

Comment: @MarkSetchell  As you can see I give the variables (first and second) just because I thought that  if I do print(first) or (second) I will get output just from pixels inside in contours.But I was wrong and I get output from all pixels in the image. Really Iam blocked at this step, I tried to do something with cv2.mean()  but I was unsuccessful..Can you give me simple explanation or example how can I take the mean of the colors..Thanks again

Comment: @J.D.thanks for youre advice.I followed mr Marks and yours explanation to find the center of shapes.I did it with the code above. But now as I wrote above, when I print(first or second) variables Iam getting  output of all pixels not from pixels which are inside contour.. İs that method impossible to take the value of pixel inside contour? I mean finding center of shapes-Giving variable to this and print this variable? thanks again **Main code above and detected centers of shapes image updated **

Comment: @Sane_or_not I find the centers of each shape,I get bgr values of each shape center but now I dont know ho to convert BGR values to color names..I tried with cv2.inRange() function lower and upper but I was unsuccessful.İf you know the main thing how to convert,can you give me a example according my code?

Answer (score 5):

Basic idea:

```
(1) Convert the image to HSV color space;
(2) Threahold the `S` to find color regions;
(3) Calculate average hsv for each color-region-maskin HSV, then convert into BGR.
```

---

For the image:

[image]

```
(1) Convert the image to HSV color space:
```

[image]

```
(2) Threahold the `S` to find color regions:
```

[image]

```
(3) Calculate average hsv for each color-region-maskin HSV, then convert into BGR.
```

[image]

---

Some links maybe useful:

```
1. just detect color regions:
```

(1) [How to detect colored patches in an image using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342025/how-to-detect-colored-patches-in-an-image-using-opencv/47343587#47343587)

(2) 
[OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/47898407#47898407)

```
2. detect specific color in HSV:
```

(1) for green: [How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image :Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)

(2) for orange: [Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/48367205#48367205)

(3) take of the `H` of the red: [How to find the RED color regions using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229126/how-to-find-the-red-color-regions-using-opencv/51230291#51230291)

```
3. If you want to crop polygon mask:
```

(1)
[Cropping Concave polygon from Image using Opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301186/cropping-concave-polygon-from-image-using-opencv-python/48301735#48301735)

Comment: thanks for explanation,but this method is not useless for me.I must did detection with code and steps above. I updated the main code and Image.Last step I find the centers of shapes so now I get the center coordinates of each shape.Now I need to  access to pixels with these coordinates..Do you have any idea,how can I access? thanks again

Comment: I know this is an old topic... are you able to provide the code for the above solution? It's perfect for what I want but don't know how to write the code to execute it.