# What is the difference between cropping an image and applying an ROI (region of interest) on the image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, convolution, roi

I'm using `opencv`.

Having a base image (`640x640`) I want to know if applying a rectangular white shape mask of (100x100), in another words, a ROI is more time consuming compared to cropping the image in the same rectangular shape (100x100).

**What I consider as being a ROI**

```
mask = np.zeros_like(original_image)
shape = np.array([[a,b,c,d]])
cv2.fillPoly(mask, shape, (255,255,255))
cv2.bitwise_and(original_image, mask)
```

**The way of cropping**

```
cropped = original_image[x:y, z:t]
```

I want to apply a function (e.g transform to grayscale) or apply a color filter on the image.

I think that doing so on the ROIed image will be more time consuming as there are many more pixels (the resulting image has the same dimensions as the original one (640x640)).

On the other hand, applying some function on the cropped image will take less time compared to the latter.

The question is: wouldn't the operation of cropping the image compensate the time needed to compute the rest of the `640x640` - `100x100` pixels?

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance

---

### Edit

I did use `timeit` as *Belal Homaidan* suggested:

```
print("CROP TIMING: ", timeit.timeit(test_crop, setup=setup, number=10000) * 1e6, "us")
print("ROI  TIMING: ", timeit.timeit(test_ROI, setup=setup, number=10000) * 1e6, "us")
```

Where `setup` was:

```
setup = """\
import cv2
import numpy as np
original_image = cv2.imread(r"C:\\Users\\path\\path\\test.png")
"""
```

Where `test_crop` was:

```
test_crop = """\
cropped = original_image[0:150, 0:150]
"""
```

And where `test_ROI` was:

```
test_ROI = """\
mask = np.zeros_like(original_image)
shape = np.array([[(0,0),(150,0),(150,150),(0,150)]])
cv2.fillPoly(mask, shape, (255,255,255))
final = cv2.bitwise_and(original_image, mask)
"""
```

The `image` was a `BGR` one with a size of `131 KB` and a resolution of `384x208` pixels.

The result was:

```
CROP TIMING:  11560.400000007576 us
ROI  TIMING:  780580.8000000524 us
```

I think that doing a ROI on an image fits when you want a specific shape, and cropping would best fit when you need rectangular shapes.

---

Comment: One difference you'll have, right off the bat, is that by processing a cropped image, you'll have less pixels to deal with. Depending on what you are doing, by operating on less pixels, you'll see a big impact in your processing chain. In regards to the actual cropping operation. I can only speak for the C++ implementation, but the operation is pretty fast. It is achieved using the same Mat information (no new data is created) and adjusting pointers at the beginning and end of the new size.

Comment: *"I want to know if **first** is more time consuming compared to **second**"* you can time it, and compare the time.[reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: So basically it doesn't matter that many pixels are black, it matters their number. **I will ask another thing** : *It is possible to crop an image in another shape other than rectangles?* Since I can't find any usefull usage for the ROI I provided in the question. It looks like cropping is better.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan, the time is fluctuating. I don't have a constant result, and I believe this happends due to the interpreter or processor queue. There is some priority hierarchy...

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu _So basically it doesn't matter that many pixels are black, it matters their number._ That’s correct. By processing fewer pixels, you pretty much are reducing the data that will go thru your operations. 
_It is possible to crop an image in another shape other than rectangles?_ No, however, you can create ROIs out of polygons, (where the pixel data will be enclosed by a polygon, and the rest will be masked) but the actual crop (the matrix shape containing your pixel data) will always be M x N.  The former can be achieved by using _poly points_ to draw a polygonal mask.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301186/cropping-concave-polygon-from-image-using-opencv-python Maybe your optimal solution involves combining the 2 concepts. Share some details if you can.