# Extract specific region from image using segmentation in python

Tags: python, json, image-processing

I am having a JSON file where the annotation is stored as below

```
{'licenses': [{'name': '', 'id': 0, 'url': ''}], 'info': {'contributor': '', 'date_created': '', 'description': '', 'url': '', 'version': '', 'year': ''}, 'categories': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'book', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ceiling', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'chair', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'floor', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'object', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'person', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'screen', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 8, 'name': 'table', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 9, 'name': 'wall', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 10, 'name': 'window', 'supercategory': ''}, {'id': 11, 'name': '__background__', 'supercategory': ''}], 'images': [{'id': 1, 'width': 848, 'height': 480, 'file_name': '153058384000.png', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}], 'annotations': [{'id': 1, 'image_id': 1, 'category_id': 7, 'segmentation': [[591.81, 146.75, 848.0, 119.83, 848.0, 289.18, 606.39, 288.06]], 'area': 38747.0, 'bbox': [591.81, 119.83, 256.19, 169.35], 'iscrowd': 0, 'attributes': {'occluded': False}}]}
```

I want to select a specific region from the image using the `''segmentation': [[591.81, 146.75, 848.0, 119.83, 848.0, 289.18, 606.39, 288.06]]'` field within `annotation` in the above json file.

The image I am using is below

[image]

I tried with Opencv and PIL, but I didn't get effective output

**Note: segmentation may have more than 8 coordinates**

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301186/cropping-concave-polygon-from-image-using-opencv-python

Comment: I don't want to crop the image. I want to find the color of the specified region